# How to redirect user to custom form when using Expression Engine with Exp-resso store

Tags: expressionengine, expresso

Okay so I need a little help here. I have a store running on expression engine with exp-resso store and I need my users to be directed to a custom form based on what product and what modifiers they have selected. once they go through the custom form they will then be placed in the checkout to review their cart.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me please and thank you!

(p.s this site is similar to www.bizfilings.com)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not a trivial undertaking, but it is possible. Have a look at the [Cart Extension Hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/developers/extension_hooks.html). Your best bet is to email the authors for guidance, they can point you in the right direction or connect you to someone experienced in extending their cart. Good luck!